# How to display return from thread into text box

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have 2 threads going on which work fine but thread 2 is giving me an error "QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread."

How can I display the return of thread 2 into "self.deviceInformation.setText"
Also, is there a way to clear the previous return and only display the current return? As it stands now, all returns get appended to the previous return

> ```
> class ListBox(QWidget):
>     
> def __init__(self):
>     super().__init__()
>
>     self.Button()
>     
> def Button(self):
>     clear_btn = QPushButton('Start Threads', self)
>     clear_btn.clicked.connect(self.thread)
>
>     self.setFixedSize(1400, 900)
>
>     self.deviceInformation = QTextEdit(self)
>     self.deviceInformation.move(860,335)
>     self.deviceInformation.resize(500,250)
>     self.deviceInformation.setReadOnly(True)
>     
>     self.show()
>
> def thread(self):
>     t1=Thread(target=self.Operation) 
>     t1.daemon = True                 
>     t1.start()
>
>     t2=Thread(target=self.Operation2)
>     t2.daemon = True                 
>     t2.start()
>     
> def Operation(self):
>     z=0
>
>     while True:
>         print(z)  
>         z=z+1                        
>         time.sleep(1)
>
> def Operation2(self):
>     zz=1
>   
>     while True:
>         print(zz)  
>         self.deviceInformation.setText(str(zz))
>         zz=zz+1                        
>         time.sleep(1)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
>    ex = ListBox()
>    sys.exit(app.exec_())
> ```

Comment: Please don't use strange ways to format code, [edit] your post and follow the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting code guide](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Btw, UI elements can *not* be accessed from external threads, you must use QThread and custom signals. Do some research on the topic, as there are literally hundreds of posts and tutorials about it.

Comment: Thanks, Using QThread and custom signals did it